# Something's wrong with my Python code (complete beginner)

Tags: python-3.x

So I am completely new to Python and can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

I need to write a program that asks for the name of the existing text file and then of the other one, that doesn't necessarily need to exist. The task of the program is to take content of the first file, convert it to upper-case letters and paste to the second file. Then it should return the number of symbols used in the file(s).

The code is:

```
file1 = input("The name of the first text file: ")
file2 = input("The name of the second file: ")
f = open(file1)
file1content = f.read()
f.close
f2 = open(file2, "w")
file2content = f2.write(file1content.upper())
f2.close
print("There is ", len(str(file2content)), "symbols in the second file.")
```

I created two text files to check whether Python performs the operations correctly. Turns out the length of the file(s) is incorrect as there were 18 symbols in my file(s) and Python showed there were 2.

Could you please help me with this one?

Comment: `f.close` is a function and should be called as `f.close()`, the same thing goes for `f2`

Comment: Thank you very much! What else is wrong?

Comment: Why are you using the return value of `f2.write()` as if it's the same as the string that was written to the file??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues I see with your code:

1. `close` is a method, so you need to use the `()` operator otherwise `f.close` does not do what your think.
2. It is usually preferred in any case to use the `with` form of opening a file -- then it is close automatically at the end.
3. the `write` [method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_write.htm) does not return anything, so `file2content = f2.write(file1content.upper())` is `None`
4. There is no reason the read the entire file contents in; just loop over each line if it is a text file.

(Not tested) but I would write your program like this:

```
file1 = input("The name of the first text file: ")
file2 = input("The name of the second file: ")
chars=0
with open(file1) as f, open(file2, 'w') as f2:
    for line in f:
        f2.write(line.upper())
        chars+=len(line)

print("There are ", chars, "symbols in the second file.")
```

Answer (score 0):

`input()` [does not do](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input) what you expect, use `raw_input()` instead.

Comment: Tagged Python 3, so [input](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input) does exactly what he thinks IF he is using Python 3.

Comment: Yes, I am using Python 3.